# Firefox seemingly waiting for asynchronous ajax to complete before updating DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, dom

I wrote the following function to get text from a log file and display it as plain text in a new browser window:

```
function openLog(logFile) {
    var win = window.open('', '_blank');
    var doc = win.document;
    var title = doc.createElement('TITLE');
    var titleText = doc.createTextNode(logFile);
    title.appendChild(titleText);
    doc.head.appendChild(title);
    doc.body.style.cursor='wait';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/getLog',
        data: { logFile : logFile },
        success: function(log) {                
            var pre = doc.createElement('PRE');
            var preText = doc.createTextNode(log);
            pre.appendChild(preText);
            doc.body.appendChild(pre);
            doc.body.style.cursor='default';
        },
        error: function() {
            doc.body.style.cursor='default';
        }
    });
};
```

The 'wait' cursor is useful for large log files.

In Chrome/IE, the 'wait' cursor is displayed immediately while the asynchronous ajax request is working in the background. In Firefox, only the 'default' cursor is displayed because it seems to be waiting for the ajax function to complete first (and once it does it is set right back to 'default').

Is there a workaround for this in Firefox? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: no, firefox does not behave as you claim - perhaps you have your cursor over an element with a cursor that overrides the body cursor style

Comment: oh, I see - because the body is empty in the **new window**, of course the cursor isn't what you expect (surprised it is in other browsers to be honest - how can you have your mouse over an empty element???? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised it works in any browser - a newly opened window would have a body with zero content therefore zero size - how do you "hover" over nothing to get the current cursor to change to the specified one? I think Firefox is the only browser that is behaving correctly!!

That being said - dummy code

```
function openLog(logFile) {
    var win = window.open('', '_blank');
    var doc = win.document;
    var title = doc.createElement('TITLE');
    var titleText = doc.createTextNode(logFile);
    title.appendChild(titleText);
    doc.head.appendChild(title);
    // change from here
    var html = doc.documentElement;
    html.style.cursor = 'wait';
    html.style.minHeight = '100vh';
    // changes finished
    //
    // dummy setTimeout for testing
    setTimeout(function () {
        // remove the cursor from HTML element
        html.style.cursor = 'default';
    }, 4000);
};
openLog('banana');
```

I'd post it as an executable snippet, but who wants to allow SO to open popups just for this :p

I use `body.parentElement` (i.e. the HTML element) - because doing this for `body` ends up with a vertical scroll bar

Comment: Interestingly enough, with the new code now I'm (occasionally) seeing something odd in chrome. Sometimes the cursor isn't changing to 'wait' unless I move the mouse. Should be easy enough to trigger that 'movement' if needed but I thought it was odd.

Comment: And actually there is something weird in OP's chrome's version. I can't reproduce from my chrome on osX.

Comment: Huh. Can confirm. Updated chrome, restarted, and I can't get it to happen again. I'll play around with it later.